# Use two-pane fragment in tabs layout

Tags: android, tabs, fragment

I'm trying to make this thing for 2 days, and I don't see how to resolve it. Explanation:

I remake the navigation interface of an application and I would like to use the Google UI guidelines for the best. So I want to include a two-pane fragments (aka. "master / detail flow") within a fragment tabs navigation! And here is the problem.

I tried this using the samples provided by the newest ADT plugin (for the both simple tab activity and master/detail. I tried using the ActionBarSherlock library too. But none of my tries had got a functional activity.

I explore the web since 4 or 5 hours, seeking for something approaching the solution I'm looking for. Is someone has a little idea of how two make it possible?

Thanks by advance for your time!

**Edit:**
Here is a mounting of what this can render. The tabs manage two or more fragments, and in one of the fragment's tab, there are two other fragments.

[image]

Comment: I don't get what you want. Can you explain it in more detail (maybe using images)?

Comment: Please go to this link http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui.html may be its helps to resolved this issue

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tried doing something similar to this before.  Unfortunately Android does not support embedded fragments.

When you click on a tab it launches a single fragment.  Inside of this single fragment you have two more fragments (the master (side navigation) fragment and detail fragment).  This is not natively supported by Android and the lifecycle of each fragment will conflict with each other and give you run-time (force-close) errors.

There are two workarounds for this.

First, you can manipulate each of the embedded fragments' lifecycles by explicitely saving and restoring it's state but this is complicated and will probably lead to more errors and headaches.

The second a preferred solution is to replace the two embedded fragments with a frame layout inside of a single fragment.  Each frame will contain a view and you can swap views in an out of the frames.  This will hurt performance if too many views are used.  If the views remain relatively simple then it won't slow things down too much.

Possibly you can reconsider the entire design and simplify it.  I.E. Just use Tabs+One level fragments or use the master-detail layout without tabs.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Apparently, Android 4.2 now includes support for nested fragments.  I will be updating the layout of my app and I will report back if it works.